# How to fix the Error of "cannot import name 'utils'"?

Tags: python, debugging, error-handling, nlp

Could anyone please fix the following error when running utils_test.py in Flan? Thanks a lot

```
  ImportError: cannot import name 'utils' from 'flan' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flan/__init__.py)
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: how do you run it? What version do you use? Did you try to update it?